# Show that the largest eigenvalue cannot exceed $\frac43$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a $4 \times4 $ positive semidefinite matrix $A$ with $1$ in its diagonal entries and $\rho$ in its off-diagonal entries,

1. If $\rho <0$, then show that the largest eigenvalue of $A$ cannot exceed $\frac43$
2. Find an eigenvector of $A$ other than $(1,1,1,1)^{\perp}$.

---

Recently, I found out that for a positive matrix largest eigenvalue is bounded by minimal row sum and maximum column sum. From that we get $\lambda_{\max}=1+3\rho$.

1. Is the result true for positive semidefinite matrices, too?
2. How to go ahead? I am not able to show the bound and also I have no clue about the second one.
3. How can one predict an eigenvector without knowing its eigenvalue?

Comment: Not only is it true of positive semidefinite matrices, it's true of *all* matrices.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, Thanks. But can you say something about its eigen value.

Comment: $\rho<0\Rightarrow 1+3\rho<1<\frac43$. Are you sure you did not mean $\lambda_{max}\leq1-3\rho$?

Comment: BTW, the largest eigenvalue is bounded by the sum of the *absolute values* of the column entries. So your upper bound is $1 + 3|\rho|$.

Comment: @GFrazao, Is that sufficient? I mean i found out that, $\lambda_{max}<1$, but question is specific about $4/3$. How do we get $1-3\rho$?.

Comment: For $\rho<0$ you have that the eigenvalues $\lambda$ must satisfy: $1+3\rho<\lambda<1-3\rho$. $A$ is positive semi-definite. Can you complete the steps?

Comment: @eyeballfrog, Ohhh. Thanks!

Comment: If you re-read my previous question, you will note that I didn't say $\lambda_{max}$ is smaller than $1$. Compute $Av$ for the $v$ you suggested in the comment of the answer.

Comment: $\rho<0\Rightarrow |\rho|=-\rho$. That's where we get the inequality from.

Comment: So, in part 1, does it want you to solve the problem *without* finding the eigenvalues individually? The eigenvalues of the matrix aren't too hard to find given that it's equal to $\rho\mathbf{1} + (1-\rho)\mathbf{I}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the matrix of all $1$s and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: @GFrazao, I understood about $1-3\rho$ part, but the row and column sum is same. Therefore, $\lambda_{max}=1-3\rho$. How did you $1+3\rho<\lambda<1-3\rho$. It looks simple, but i am still confused. Also, i couldn't find the result for bound on largest eigen value for *any* matrix.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, Anyway is fine. They didn't mention any.

Answer (score 2):

> “2. Find an eigen vector of *A*
> other than $(1,1,1,1)^{\rm T}$.”

> How can one predict an eigen vector without knowing its eigen value?

Let $u=(1,1,1,1)^{\rm T}$. Then your matrix is of the form $A=\rho uu^{\rm T} + (-\rho+1)I_4$ and has rank one. Try to come up with a vector *v* that is orthogonal to *u*, i.e., that all its entries add up to zero, and see what happens when you compute *Av*.

Comment: We can have $v=(1,-1,1,-1)^{\perp}$.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean $A - (1-\rho)I = \rho uu^{T}$ has rank $1$, not $A$ itself.